# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `foo'

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a command I am trying to alias for simplicity:

```
php artisan route:list | (head -n 3; grep checkout)
```

This command shows me the header of this table and searches for the route. The result looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                        | Name                                               | Action                                                                        | Middleware                                           |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|        | POST     | profile/auctions/checkout                  | user-portal-profile-auctions-checkout              | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                   | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST     | profile/deals/checkout                     | user-portal-profile-deals-checkout                 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST     | profile/quotes/checkout                    | user-portal-profile-quotes-checkout                | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                    | web,auth                                             |
```

So this is what I have in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias findRoute='php artisan route:list | (head -n 3; grep $1)'
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `checkout'
```

What gives? Why will it not accept my argument?

I have tried using single and double quotes in the argument I pass.

I have tried using single and double quotes in the alias. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alias expansion is just text replacement followed by another round of parsing by the shell.

When you enter

```
findRoute checkout
```

That's first expanded to:

```
php artisan route:list | (head -n 3; grep $1) checkout
```

And that result is again parsed as shell code. That's invalid shell code here.

You'd want to use a script or function instead here. Like:

```
findRoute() {
  php artisan route:list | {
    head -n 3
    grep -e "$1"
  }
}
```

Now, beware that `head` may read more than 3 lines, even though it outputs only 3 as most `head` implementations read by entire blocks. That means `grep` would not get to see that part.

If your `sed` is the GNU implementation, you can replace `head -n3` with `sed -u 3q`, where `sed` reads the input one byte at a time so as not read past the third newline characters.

Alternatively, you could use `awk` instead as:

```
findRoute() {
  php artisan route:list |
    PATTERN=$1 awk 'NR <= 3 || $0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"]'
}
```

Beware `$1` is then interpreted as an *extended* regular expression (like for `grep -E`) instead of a *basic* one (with `grep` without `-E`). For a substring search (as in `grep -F`), replace with:

```
findRoute() {
  php artisan route:list |
    PATTERN=$1 awk 'NR <= 3 || index($0, ENVIRON["PATTERN"])'
}
```

Comment: Wow. Okay that makes sense because of the ()'s. So if I wasn't using head and ended with `grep $1` it would take my argument.

Comment: No. I am still wrong. Aliasing is just text replacement like you said. I would need to use a function. Otherwise, the argument just gets tacked on to the end.